# A question about topologies on the product of two topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that if (X, Y) are two topological spaces, then $X\times Y$ with the product topology is the coarsest topology for which the projection functions on $X$ and $Y$ are continuous. I have shown that the projection functions are continuous on $X\times Y$ with the product topology.

So now I suppose that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X\times Y$ s.t. the projection maps are continuous. Let $U$ be open in $X\times Y$ with the product topology. Then $U=A\times B$ where $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$. Since $A$ is open in $X$, we have that $A\times Y$ is in $\mathcal{T}$. Similarly $X\times B\in T$. So $(A\times Y)\cap(X\times B)=U\in \mathcal{T}$.

I am having a problem with the assumption that I made; if $A$ is open in $X$ then $A\times Y$ is open in any topology on $X\times Y$. Is this true and does my proof look good in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume that $U$ has the form $A\times B$ for some open $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$: sets of that kind are a *base* for the product topology, but they are not in general the whole topology. However, you *have* shown that all sets of that form must be open if the projection maps are continuous, so by the definition of a topology all unions of them must be open as well. Thus it actually does follow from the work that you've done that every product open set must be open, though what you wrote is not sufficient to establish this.

Comment: Concerning the first sentence. Is it not the case that A would be the union of basis elements, and as such would be open in X?

Comment: @H_B: $A$ is a union of sets in any base for the topology of $X$, but that's beside the point. In order to argue that $A\times Y$ is open in $X\times Y$ because the projection is continuous you must be assuming that $A$ is open in $X$ anyway. The problem is with your (generally false) assumption that every open set in $X\times Y$ is a product set. For a counterexample just look at the open unit disk in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: So how can I describe the elements of the product topology. All I am told is that the elements $(A,B)$ where $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$ form a basis for the product space. And we define the topology as the arbitrary unions of these $(A,B)$'s. Could you show me how to fix my argument? I think I might better understand that way. I am very confused right now.

Comment: @H_B: You want to show that if $\mathcal{T}$ is such that the projection maps are continuous, and $\tau$ is the product topology, then $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{T}$. Let $$\mathscr{B}=\{A\times B:A\text{ is open in }X\text{ and }B\text{ is open in }Y\}\;.$$ You’ve shown that $\mathscr{B}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$. Now use the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\tau$. If $U\in\tau$, then $U$ is the union of members of $\mathscr{B}$, so it’s the union of members of $\mathcal{T}$, so it’s in $\mathcal{T}. Thus, $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{T}$, as desired.

Comment: Ok great I totally understand that. I have two questions. I am still a little confused on why I cant say the form of $U$ is $(A,B)$ where $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$. It seems to me that if $U$ is the union of elements of the form $(A,B)$ then it also is of them form $(A,B)$. So there is a U that is not in this form? I am not questioning you b.t.w., I know you are right, I just don't understand yet. 

question 2) in writing question two I figured out the answer to question 2.

Comment: @H_B: Yes, in general there are lots of open sets in $X\times Y$ that are not of that form. I gave an example: $$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R:x^2+y^2<1\}\;,$$ the open unit disk in the plane. It’s clearly not of the form $U\times V$ for any open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\Bbb R$. Unions don’t commute with Cartesian products: the union of products is not in general a product of unions.

Comment: AHHH! Thanks for your time, I fully understand now.

Comment: How could we describe the unit circle as arbitrary unions of elements of the form $(A,B)$ where $A,B$ open in $\mathbb{R}$? If you are sick of me, I understand and you don't need to answer this:)

Comment: @H_B: Okay, I’m [there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20350/discussion-between-h-b-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to do that.

Comment: @H_B: Just show that for each $\langle x,y\rangle$ in the open unit disk there’s an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ is a subset of the disk. It involves a little messy algebra, but it’s not really hard.

Comment: OK great. Thanks again.

Comment: @H_B: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect; just put the indiscrete topology on $X\times Y$ (that is, only the sets $\varnothing$ and $X\times Y$ are open). Then $A\times Y$ won't be open, for any $A\not=\varnothing, X$.

Comment: The OP is correct: if the projection maps are continuous, and $A$ is open in $X$, then necessarily $A\times Y$ is open in $X\times Y$.

Comment: My point was that the final sentence is not true without implicit assumptions, i.e. the projection maps being continuous.

Comment: That assumption is clearly stated at the beginning of the OP’s second paragraph.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have made that more clear. And I understand why its true now (with the maps). Since A is open its preimage is open by definition.